# Wrong number of arguments while seeding the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model generated by the following method

```
$ rails generate model user first_name last_name age:integer
```

Then I am trying to populate the db by using the following in seeds.rb.

```
User.destroy_all

User.create![
    {first_name: "Vamsi", last_name: "Pavan", age: 21},
    {first_name: "Vani", last_name: "Pavani", age: 20}
]
```

When rake db:seed is done, I am getting the following error.

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:358:in `[]'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/rails/coursera/advanced_ar/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through `each` item of this array.

```
users = [
  {first_name: "Vamsi", last_name: "Pavan", age: 21},
  {first_name: "Vani", last_name: "Pavani", age: 20}
]

users.each{|user| User.create! user}
```

Comment: Cool! But what is the fault in my approach. Your code works fine!

Comment: Try to add parentheses in method call.

Comment: Yeah, it works. This guy is culprit :p https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course2-module2-advanced-ar/blob/master/db/seeds.rb

Answer (score 2):

you **forgot space** between method and arguments

```
User.create! [
    {first_name: "Vamsi", last_name: "Pavan", age: 21},
    {first_name: "Vani", last_name: "Pavani", age: 20}
]
```

or wrap argiments `()`

```
User.create!([
    {first_name: "Vamsi", last_name: "Pavan", age: 21},
    {first_name: "Vani", last_name: "Pavani", age: 20}
])
```

in this case you will create all objects (users) in single transaction

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this helps :)